# is there any java template engine benchmarks?

Tags: templates, benchmarking, template-engine, freemarker

I'm looking for fastest and reliable java template engine. Is there any benchmarks for microseconds capable template engines?

I've found engines:
http://code.google.com/p/mist4j/wiki/USAGE
http://lazyj.sourceforge.net/

Scrpting languages template benchmarks http://www.kuwata-lab.com/tenjin/
there velocity sucks.

I'm also interested in compare of ability of engines found and freemarker and StringTemplate engines.

Comment: Last I seen it (and it certainly didn't change) Velocity wasn't compiled to anything, it just runs the AST directly. And the AST nodes will use `Map.get` and reflection to get the values. FreeMarker does the same (that I'm sure of), and it should be slower as it has to do more (more features). OTOH template languages written for "script languages" (like Python) often transform to the host script language, and then the alredy highly tuned script language implementation (like CPython) will do its magic... hence the speed difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran for 10000 times loop. Rythm was failing to load template, so i need to exclude that in my test...

stringbuilder:
     [java] ntimes: 10000, real time: 641(msec)

freemarker:
     [java] ntimes: 10000, real time: 1602(msec)

velocity:
     [java] ntimes: 10000, real time: 1035(msec)

jamon:
     [java] ntimes: 10000, real time: 633(msec)

httl:
     [java] ntimes: 10000, real time: 479(msec)

jmte:
     [java] ntimes: 10000, real time: 2193(msec)

httl was outperforming in all tests with 100 time loop, 1000 time loop and finally 10000 loop (also mentioned above).

Comment: can you test for StringTemplate as well? or share how can one do it for newer template engines?

Answer (score 6):

Here is one template engine benchmark: https://github.com/greenlaw110/template-engine-benchmarks, which benchmarks the following java template engines:

- stringbuilder - the baseline. manually created page using StringBulder
- freemarker - v2.3.19
- velocity - v1.7
- rythm - v1.0-b2
- httl - 1.0.7
- beetl - 1.2
- jamon - 2.3
- jangod - no version info
- thymeleaf - 2.0.15

Comment: Interesting benchmark, but I wonder why don't you publish your results. Maybe I'm a bit too lazy :)

Comment: The thing is template engine is updating, and result might not be relevant to new versions. So it's better for you to pickup latest version of each template engine jar file, put them into the lib folder and run the benchmark. Anyway here you can find a snapshot of the benchmark result: http://rythmengine.org/doc/feature#high-performance

Comment: Thanks. I think this way we can get an idea of the numbers, although they can change a little over time.

Comment: This benchmark is missing Handlebars and Mustache, but there's a fork (with a languishing pull request) where they've been added: https://github.com/agentgt/template-engine-benchmarks

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good benchmark for java template engines

https://github.com/jreijn/spring-comparing-template-engines

According to it:

```
Jade4j                  567.7 seconds
Handlebars              147.7 seconds
Scalate - Scaml         33.33 seconds
Pebble                  27.92 seconds
HTTL                    24.61 seconds
Thymeleaf               24.09 seconds
Velocity                23.07 seconds
Freemarker              11.80 seconds
jTwig                   10.95 seconds
Mustache (JMustache)    8.836 seconds
JSP                     7.888 seconds
```

The best part is: You can reproduce the benchmark yourself and verify the results :)